# scons check for available file without caching result

Tags: scons

I'm trying to use scons functions to detect if a specific header file is available.  Given a file `main.cpp` with a `#include "fns.h"`. I've created this:

```
env = Environment(CXXFLAGS='-I.')
conf = Configure(env)
if not conf.CheckCXXHeader('fns.h'):
    print 'please get fns.h'
    Exit(1)

env.Program('main.cpp')
```

The first time I run it, it actually checks for the header, but after that it always uses the cached result

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ header file fns.h... no
please get fns.h

$ touch fns.h
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ header file fns.h... yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o main.o -c -I. main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.

$ rm fns.h # delete it
$ scons # should check again here, but doesn't
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ header file fns.h... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o main.o -c -I. main.cpp
main.cpp:1:17: fatal error: fns.h: No such file or directory
 #include "fns.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the SCons manual (man scons), the command-line option you're looking for is "--config=force". You can also make it the default behavior for your build by setting the config option in an SConscript file:

```
SetOption('config', 'force')
```